# SelectizeJs: duplicate select menus are being creacted when generating select menus dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, selectize.js

I'm trying to create multiple `selectize` select menu's dynamically, by pressing the plus icon.

Please test the code below, the problem is that if I comment out this line

```
selectize_init(select_class, options, results);
```

from `addOrRemoveSelectContainer` function, everything will be cloned correctly but `selectize` will stop working. You won't be able to select anything

If I leave this line

```
selectize_init(select_class, options, results);
```

Then duplicate select menus will be created and only one of them works.

[image]

I have tried using

```
  $(className).selectize({...})
```

instead of

```
  $(className).last().selectize({...})
```

But the problem wasn't fixed. And I don't want to use `maxItems: null` and enable multi-select because each select menu has other options related to that specific selection.

```js
var audiences_value = []
let audiences = [
{id: 1, title: 'foo'}, 
{id: 2, title: 'bar'},
{id: 3, title: 'foobar'},
{id: 4, title: 'baz'}
];

function addOrRemoveSelectContainer(
  btn,
  action,
  container,
  select_class,
  options,
  results
) {
  var $selectContainer = $(btn).parent(container);

  if (action == "add") {
    var $clone = $selectContainer.last().clone();

    $selectContainer.last().after($clone);
   // NOTE: if you comment out the line below
   // selectize_init(select_class, options,results);
   // The select field will be cloned correctly
   // but you cannot select anything
   
   selectize_init(select_class, options, results);
  } else if (action == "remove") {
    if ($(container).length > 1) {
      $selectContainer.remove();
    }
  }
}

function selectize_init(className, options, results) {
  $(className)
    .last()
    .selectize({
      maxItems: 1,
      valueField: "title",
      labelField: "title",
      searchField: "title",
      options: options,
      create: true,
      onChange: function (tenant) {
        results.push(tenant);
      },
    });

  return results;
}

audiences_value = selectize_init(".audiences", audiences, audiences_value)
```

```css
.select-label,
.select {
    display: inline-block;

}

.select {
    width: 20rem;
}

.selectize-control {
    margin: 2em;
}

.select-container {
    display: block;
}

.add-row,
.remove-row {
    border: 0;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.15.2/js/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha512-IOebNkvA/HZjMM7MxL0NYeLYEalloZ8ckak+NDtOViP7oiYzG5vn6WVXyrJDiJPhl4yRdmNAG49iuLmhkUdVsQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.15.2/css/selectize.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-pTaEn+6gF1IeWv3W1+7X7eM60TFu/agjgoHmYhAfLEU8Phuf6JKiiE8YmsNC0aCgQv4192s4Vai8YZ6VNM6vyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    
<div class="select-container audiences-container">
 <select class="select audiences" required></select>
  <button type="button" class="add-row bg-success text-white" onclick="addOrRemoveSelectContainer(this, 'add', '.audiences-container', '.audiences', audiences, audiences_value)"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="remove-row bg-danger text-white" onclick="addOrRemoveSelectContainer(this ,'remove', '.audiences-container')"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi, you can remove the dynamically generated elements by selectize.js , only append your original select and initialise it .

Comment: @Swati you mean like this `$('audiences').last().remove()` ? yeah could work, haven't thought of it, will give it a try, thanks for suggesting that

Comment: Like this `$clone.find(".selectize-control , select > option").remove();` this will remove the dynamically generated divs . Add that line before appending it to your DOM and then initialize it.

Comment: @Swati good solution, my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was described in the comment above.

$('#CONTROL_ID').last().remove()